# Redirect ALL traffic to https including subdomains and remove www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, https

I am trying to create a .htaccess file with the following rules:

```
http://www.example.com/test => https://example.com/test
http://test.example.com/test => https://test.example.com/test
https://www.example.com/test => https://example.com/test
```

This is my current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.nebla.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://nebla.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Howerver this causes some odd behaviour:

```
http://www.nebla.co.uk/ => https://nebla.co.uk/public_html
```

It also causes a redirect loop on subdomains.

Comment: How about having a `RewriteRule`  preceded by a `RewriteCond HTTPS off` ?  What is the config to allow the redirect you have got? (the one with the `public_html` in the destination part? Have you tried to read the docs? e.g. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I have indeed read the docs and searched for help, however everybody seems to want the main site to go to https and all subdomains to go to http, I do not want this behaviour. I have updated my question.

Comment: there is nothing with `public_html` in these rules. Any chance there is something defined in the "main" configuration files (usually `httpd.conf`, might be in `/etc/httpd` or '/etc/apache2` for *nix servers, not sure where they are for other OS. (oh, and btw, I do not get the redirect to `public_html` when testing)

Comment: Unfortunately I can not access any configuration files as i am using a hosting service, I guess this makes the question more "why is public_html" being added"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix my behaviour by instead of using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.nebla.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://nebla.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I changed `$1` to `%{REQUEST_URI}` like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.nebla.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://nebla.co.uk/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```